# How can I edit multiple types (with same base) on the same view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Lets say I have two classes one base class:

```
public class BaseModel {

}
```

And a couple of children:

```
public class FooModel : BaseModel {

}

public class BarModel : BaseModel {

}
```

Now my view I would like to expect a model like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<BaseModel>
```

And in my action I would pass in child classes along the lines of:

```
return View(new List<BaseModel>(){ new FooModel(), new BarModel() })
```

I would then edit these on one page, using `EditFor` (This works fine)

The problem is when I post back I would like to be able to cast these types to there implementation types, but this doesn't work. If I try and cast it, it is null or an exception is thrown.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BaseModelUpdate(IList<BaseModel > model)
{
// I would like to access items in the list as FooModel and BarModel 
}
```

How can I achieve this? (getting the items in the list back to their child class types?)

I was thinking I could try and use TryUpdateModel?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remember that when you post a form back in MVC, you don't actually get objects from the browser. You get a bunch of key-value pairs, and the framework "magically" builds the objects it expects from them for you. Which objects it expects is determined from the static type signatures in your code – the @model directive, or the controller method parameters. (Not sure which, I'm not that familiar with the specifics of ASP.NET MVC.) It doesn't automatically remember which objects it sent previously.

Comment: So I will have to use TryUpdate then...:S uncool.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the index of the item in the collection.

Here is the controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return 
            View(new List<BaseModel>() { new BarModel() { BaseProp = "Bar" }, new FooModel() { BaseProp = "Foo" } });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IList<BaseModel> model)
    {
        return this.View(model);
    }

}
```

As You can see, there is nothing special about it. The magic is in the view:

```
@using MvcApplication1.Models
@model IList<MvcApplication1.Models.BaseModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
    //Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h2>title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
     {

         @Html.EditorFor(p => p[i])
     }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

As you can see, the expression passed to EditorFor contains the index of the current item in the collection. Why this is required is explained [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx). In brief, EditorFor returns an input element for each property whose name attribute contains the index of the item within the collection, e.g.

```
<input class="text-box single-line" name="[0].BaseProp" type="text" value="Bar" />
```

**UPDATE**

If you are trying to preserve the type of the objects you will need to have a special property in the model which will store the specific model type and a custom `IModelBinder` implementation which will create the specific model instance based on that property. 
Bellow are the model classes. The `Type` property will render as a hidden input:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public class BaseModel
    {

        public string BaseProp { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public virtual string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return _type ?? this.GetType().FullName;
            }
            set
            {
                _type = value;
            }
        }
        private string _type;
    }

    public class FooModel : BaseModel
    {
        public string FooProp { get; set; }
    }

    public class BarModel :BaseModel
    {
        public string BarProp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is an example implementation of the custom model binder:

```
    public class BaseModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            // call to get the BaseModel data so we can access the Type property
            var obj = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
            var bm = obj as BaseModel;
            if(bm != null)
            {
                //call base.BindModel again but this time with a new 
                // binding context based on the spefiic model type
                obj = base.BindModel(
                    controllerContext,
                    new ModelBindingContext(bindingContext)
                        {
                            ModelMetadata =
                                ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, Type.GetType(bm.Type)),
                                ModelName = bindingContext.ModelName
                        });
            }
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

You need to register the custom binder on application_start:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(BaseModel), new BaseModelBinder());
```

Comment: i already do this, this is not the issue, I get the values back perfectly as the basemodel, but I would like to convert these to their instance types.

Comment: okay, wow, let me give this a go and get back to you - thanks in advance.

Comment: @shenku just bear in mind that I have added an extra line of code in the CreateModel method of the BaseModelBinder class. Otherwise the properties that are specific for FooModel and BarModel classes are not bound properly.

Comment: @shenku refactored a bit. Much simpler and easier to read now.